# 'com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView' package not found error in netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, swing

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


class JavaxBrowerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Browser browser = new Browser();

        BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JxBrowser Google Maps");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setSize(700, 500);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        browser.loadURL("http://maps.google.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Did you include all the required binaries? Team dev have quite good documentation

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jxbrowser jars to Libraries in NetBeans. See step 3 "Add the required libraries" in this page:

https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000012871-jxbrowser-in-netbeans